# Better Speed if removing AsNoTraking - why? - Entity Framework 5.0 - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5

I have a strange problem with a SQL Query generated with Entity Framework. I have the lowing scenario:

(All times are from SQL Profiler, so not EF Code is involved)

- I restart the Server
- I start SQL Proviler to see the times
- I run the Query from the App over EF - It Takes 12 Seconds
- I copy the Query from SQL Proviler to SQL Query Analyser - It Takes 340 ms
- I run the Query again from the App over EF - It Takes 12 Seconds
- I run the Query again from SQL Query Analyser - It Takes 320 ms
  (I can repeat this procedure over and over with the same result)

Also, if I run the Query from SQL Query Analyser directly after a restart of the Server it is only taking around 1 Second the first time and than the same scenario discribed above.

**Edit: I found a solution but I don't know why this is speeding up the query. So it is still a open question...???**

**I used the .AsNoTracking Method in the LINQ Query. If I remove this Statement the query is executed in 320 ms. Could this be something about the locking level EF uses with NoTracking???**

Any hints/ideas would be really great.
Markus

Answer (score 0):

So, I answer my own question - after many days of searching I opened a microsoft incident.

The real reason is still not clear but somehow SQL Server was choosing a different execution plan for the query if executed over EF. So there are three solutions:

1) Change the indices on the tables so the Execution plan is clear
2) Add a hint to the Query (Not possible right now with EF)
3) Create a plan_guide for this query in SQL Server

I desided to use the first solution.